# Interpreting ACF and PACF plots for SARIMA model

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I'm new to time series and used the monthly ozone concentration data from Rob Hyndman's [website](https://datamarket.com/data/set/22u8/ozon-concentration-downtown-l-a-1955-1972#!ds=22u8&display=line) to do some forecasting.

After doing a log transformation and differencing by lags 1 and 12 to get rid of the trend and seasonality respectively, I plotted the ACF and PACF shown [in this image][2]. Am I on the right track and how would I interpret this as a SARIMA?

There seems to be a pattern every 11 lags in the PACF plot, which makes me think I should do more differencing (at 11 lags), but doing so gives me a worse plot. 
I'd really appreciate any of your help!

EDIT:
I got rid of the differencing at lag 1 and just used lag 12 instead, and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HbAc.png) is what I got for the ACF and PACF.

From there, I deduced that: SARIMA(1,0,1)x(1,1,1) (AIC: 520.098)
or SARIMA(1,0,1)x(2,1,1) (AIC: 521.250)
would be a good fit, but auto.arima gave me (3,1,1)x(2,0,0) (AIC: 560.7) normally and (1,1,1)x(2,0,0) (AIC: 558.09) without stepwise and approximation.

I am confused on which model to use, but based on the lowest AIC, SAR(1,0,1)x(1,1,1) would be the best? Also, the thing that concerns me is that none of the models pass the Ljung-Box test. Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite difficult to manually select a model order that will perform well at forecasting a dataset.  This is why Rob has built the 'auto.arima' function in his R forecast package, to figure out the model that may perform best based on certain metrics.

When you see a pacf plot with significantly negative lags that usually means you have over differenced your data.  Try removing the 1st order difference and keeping the 12 order difference.  Then carry on making your best guess.

I'd recommend trying his auto.arima function and passing it a time series object with frequency = 12.  He has a good writeup of seasonal arima models here:

https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/9

If you would like more insight into manually selecting a SARIMA model order, this is a good read:

https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/67

In response to your Edit:
I think it would be beneficial to this post if you clarify your objective.  Which of the following are you trying to achieve?

1. Find a model where residuals satisfy Ljung Box Test
2. Produce the most accurate out of sample forecast
3. Manually select lag orders such that ACF and PACF plots show no significant lags remaining.

In my opinion, #2 is the most sought after objective so I'll assume that is your goal.  From my experience, #3 produces poor results out of sample. In regards to #1, I am usually not concerned about correlations remaining in the residuals.  We know we do not have the true model for this time-series, so I do not feel there's any reason to expect an approximate model that performs well out of sample to not have left something behind in the residuals that is more complex perhaps, or nonlinear etc.

To provide you another SARIMA result, I ran this data through some code I've developed and found the following equation produced the minimal error on a cross-validation period.

```
Final model is: 
SARIMA [0,1,1] [1,1,1]12 with a constant using the log normal of the time-series.

The errors in the cross validation period are:
MAPE = 16%
MAE = 0.46
RSQR = 74%
```

[image: Results]

Here is the Partial Autocorrelation plot of the residuals for your information.
[image: PACF Plot for Residuals]

This is roughly similar in methodology to selecting an equation based on AICc to my understanding, but is ultimately a different approach.  Regardless, if your objective is out of sample accuracy, I'd recommend evaluating equations in terms of their out of sample accuracy versus in-sample fit, tests, or plots.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explanation! One thing I'm unsure of is that you mentioned having negative significant lags in the PACF meant overdifferencing, but the plot you showed above is not overdifferencing? Because this is for an assignment, I am required to achieve #3 (selecting the lags manually). Am I on the right track with using SARIMA(1,0,1)x(1,1,1) and (1,0,1)x(2,1,1) or is there a way I can select the model with the lowest AIC or AICc using a for loop?

Comment: The plot above probably does indicate some over-differencing, but like I said, I landed on this equation using an automated approach and I really don't pay a lot of attention to the correlations in the residuals when I'm done (as long as the residuals are a relatively small percentage of the time-series' itself).  You said you need to select the lags manually, but also wonder if you can use lowest AICc in a loop.  The R package 'forecast' selects a model using the lowest AICc in a loop I think.  So just use that package if you're allowed to.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I really appreciate it. I looked up the forecast function you were talking about, and it turned out to be auto.arima (what a coincidence, so thank you for telling me about it). Using that, I got a model which was one of the models I found by looking at the lags, but the AIC is not the smallest. Should I use the model that I found using auto.arima or the one with the smallest AIC? (does the AIC matter more than the best model picked by auto.arima?)

Comment: You're welcome.  The auto.arima function takes some shortcuts when evaluating the various combinations of models in order to speed up the process.  Perhaps it skipped the model that you found manually.  Try running auto.arima using the following parameters:

stepwise=FALSE, approximation=FALSE

Comment: I did that and it gave me a model with a higher AIC than the first time around. In that case, I'm thinking of sticking to the one I found manually, although I'm not sure if this is a good choice to make

Comment: All models are wrong when it comes to fitting to time-series data, some just do better than others at achieving your objective.  So, I'd now test the model you arrived at to see if it is 'good' enough for you.